# Doctrine Query reverse join?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

[image: BDD Schema]

I have these relations.

I need to retrieve all contents but order by `star.content_Idcontent` first.

It works with easy SQL:

```
SELECT content.idcontent
FROM content
LEFT JOIN star ON content.idcontent = star.content_Idcontent 
ORDER BY star.content_Idcontent DESC,content.idcontent
```

But I don't know how to do it with Doctrine because content is not the owner of the relation.

Must I create a bidirectional relation or is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a query in ContentRepository like:

```
$qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('content')
    ->join(
         'App\Entity\Star',
         'star',
         \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\LeftJoin::WITH,
         'content.idcontent = star.content_Idcontent '
         )
    ->orderBy('star.content_Idcontent', 'DESC')
;

$qb->getResult();
```

Assuming that your Entity `Star` is located in `App\Entity\Star`

Comment: note:  on my side I had to do  `content = star.content`  (i.e follow the doctrine annotation convention not the database column names)